# How to get large files size without high io usage in php?

Tags: php, file

I have some huge files, for example 3-9GB large files. But my problem whe i use

> $size = filesize($file);

than I got really huge io ussage. It almost kill my apache server. Is there any other method for this?

```
private function pieces ( $handle, $piece_length, $last = true ) {
        static $piece, $length;
        if ( empty( $length ) )
            $length = $piece_length;
        $pieces = null;
        while ( ! feof( $handle ) ) {
            if ( ( $length = strlen( $piece .= fread( $handle, $length ) ) ) == $piece_length )
                $pieces .= self::pack( $piece );
            elseif ( ( $length = $piece_length - $length ) < 0 )
                return self::set_error( new Exception( 'Invalid piece length!' ) );
                        sleep(1);
        }
        fclose( $handle );
        return $pieces . ( $last && $piece ? self::pack( $piece ) : null);
    }
```

This is my code that tries to get the file size and make pieces hashs... I actually have a file sharing website and I whould like to generate torrent files for uploaded files, but when I generate the torrent this function eats all my HDD. (I whould like to use torrent, becouse if I download with my browser that can be iterrupted. But If I use torrent, than I can continue my downloading...)

Comment: What O/S? I cannot reproduce this, `filesize` returns instantly on a 8G file

Comment: It's debian 64 bit. It's not 100% filesize is the bad. Maybe the fopen? They are in the same function.

Comment: That's definetly possible, try executing `die();` on each line, to determine which line causes the slowdown

Comment: Always narrow down your problem to a simplified example. Pasting a single line of code here should mean you've run a script with just that line of code and reproduced the problem. If it takes more than one line to reproduce, the question should include them all.

Comment: OK, so you're not just reading the length of this file, you're reading its entire contents; that's rather different. What, in a nutshell, does `self::pack` do, and return? I'm guessing it somehow resets `$piece` to an empty string? Is there somewhere that then writes the data to a new file on disk? It seems like there are an awful lot of places in this program which could be responsible for the high I/O, and you really need to do some proper debugging to find out where the problem actually is before you start looking for solutions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `get_headers();`
Example:
`get_headers('http://your-server.com/your-file.zip');`

Use `Content-Length`